# Simple differentiation question that I am unsure about

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am in the process of re-learning differentiation and am stuck on this as part of a larger problem.

Can you explain to me why when differentiated 4 times this:
$$y = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{y_n}{n!} x^n$$

equals this:
$$y^{(4)}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{y_{n+4}}{n!}x^n.$$ ?

This is the larger problem I am trying to solve:

*Any function y of a real variable x that solves the differential equation:*
$\frac{d^4y}{dx^4} -16y =0$
*may be represented by a power series of the form:*
$y = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{y_n}{n!} x^n$
*where the coefficients $y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,...$ of this power series are real numbers. Find values of these coefficients $y_n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4,...$ that yields a solution to the above differential equation with $y_0=1, y_1=0, y_2=−4$ and $y_3=0.$*

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to know something about this series before you can differentiate "under the summation". Does the series converge absolutely?

Comment: I just realized I wrote the question down wrong, I have it fixed now. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives, we can just differentiate each term in the summation to get the derivative of $y$. You have to be careful for infinite sums, but it works here.
So we take each term in the series with the form
$$
a_n = \frac{y_n}{n!} x^n,
$$
where each $y_n$ is a constant with $n \ge 0$. If we differentiate each term in the sum, we get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(a_n) = \frac{n y_n}{n!}x^{n-1} = \frac{y_n}{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}, \qquad n \ge 1
$$
We have $n\ge1$ as the term $a_0 = y_0$ is just a constant so its derivative is $0$.

If we repeat this calculation three more times we get
$$
\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(a_n) = \frac{y_n}{(n-4)!}x^{n-4}, \qquad n\ge4.
$$
But we can rewrite this in terms of a different index $k = n-4$ as
$$
\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(a_k) = \frac{y_{k+4}}{(k)!}x^{k}, \qquad k\ge0.
$$